# PDAL Reader.las and Writer.las warning: 'found invalid value of '0' for point's return number'

Tags: error, lidar, filter, las, pdal

I am trying to read and write LAS (*.las) file using PDAL but getting the following warning messages by PDAL's [LAS reader](https://www.pdal.io/stages/readers.las.html) and [writer](https://www.pdal.io/stages/writers.las.html) for [ASPRS LAS](https://www.asprs.org/committee-general/laser-las-file-format-exchange-activities.html) files.

```
(pdal pipeline readers.las Warning) C:/denoise\lake.las: 
      Found invalid value of '0' for point's return number.

(pdal pipeline readers.las Warning) C:/denoise\lake.las: 
      Found invalid value of '0' for point's number of returns.
```

I'm trying to remove noise from las file using the code below:

```
 { "pipeline":[ "C:/denoise/lake1.las", { "type": "filters.outlier", "method": "statistical", "multiplier": 3, "mean_k": 8 }, { "type": "filters.range", "limits": "Classification![7:7],Z[-100:3000]" }, { "type": "writers.las", "compression": "true", "minor_version": "2", "dataformat_id": "0", "filename":"C:/denoise/clean.las" } ] }
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about "not being done correctly" with some more information as to why you think this is the case.

Comment: I'm trying to remove noise from las file using the code below;
{
  "pipeline":[
   "C:/denoise/lake1.las",
    {
            "type": "filters.outlier",
            "method": "statistical",
            "multiplier": 3,
            "mean_k": 8
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.range",
            "limits": "Classification![7:7],Z[-100:3000]"
        },
        {
            "type": "writers.las",
            "compression": "true",
            "minor_version": "2",
            "dataformat_id": "0",
            "filename":"C:/denoise/clean.las"
        }
  ]
}

Answer (score 2):

> (pdal pipeline readers.las Warning) C:/denoise\lake.las: Found invalid value of '0' for point's return number.

'0' is not a valid return number in LAS, and PDAL is just warning you here about it. It should pass it on through without touching it though.

Comment: But the output file that pdal creates in this case is of 1KB and the same code removes noise from laz file correctly.

Comment: I've figured out that the point cloud has been created from stereo pairs thus there will be no return of the beam information with the points.

Comment: _"It should pass it on through without touching it though"_. [Here](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/617#issuecomment-319613470) @abellgithub is proposing to coerce 0 to 1 when reading it into PDAL and leaving a warning message. This was not implemented, right?

Comment: Yes _"filters.assign"_ can be used to replace the **0** return number and number of return with **1**.