# Converting .las to .pcd file using PDAL?

Tags: convert, lidar, las, pdal, pcd

Is it possible to translate .las files to .pcd with [PDAL](http://www.pdal.io/)? If so, using which tool? I need an example about how to set the command-line with such tool.

If it is not possible (or alternatively), is there other open source software that can translate .las to .pcd?

Comment: As you've been told in **three** forums and privately emailed now, it is not an error about return numbers, it is a warning.

https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/1629
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250008/pdal-reader-las-and-writer-las-error-found-invalid-value-of-0-for-points-re
https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/617#issuecomment-319613470

Comment: Return 0 is not warning its An error Because the output result is nothing only in this case ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [PDAL](http://pdal.io) [PCD Writer](https://www.pdal.io/stages/writers.pcd.html) can write .pcd files. For it to work, you must have linked the [PCL libraries](http://pointclouds.org/) at compile time. The [PDAL OSGeo4W build](https://www.pdal.io/workshop/osgeo4w.html) does not have PCL support. If you are unable to build PDAL with PCL support yourself, one possibility is to use [PDAL's Docker](https://www.pdal.io/quickstart.html) containers to achieve your task -- those have PCL linked.

Then, simply run `pdal translate`:

Using your own PDAL build with PCL linked:

```
pdal translate input.las output.pcd
```

With Docker:

```
docker run -v /c/Users/hobu/:/data pdal/pdal:1.5 ^
       pdal translate /data/input.las /data/output.pcd
```

Comment: Thanks Howard Butler For this  my finding also V Near to this Thanks 
Again :) 
But Howard I am stuck on 1 point and can't move further /Don't find any suitable solution 
Please Share Your Expert Opinion /Experience in this Regard 

**Classified an UnClassified .las file**

For more please see this post 

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251053/classified-an-unclassified-las-file

Comment: pdal translate -i test.las -o test_out.pcd
Gives This error  ""PDAL: Couldn't create writer stage of type writers.pcd""
@howard 
I also Find this Issue on GIT HUB (Issues Section ) and I Don't How to Resolve This 
For More Please See This LINK   
https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/1410

Comment: Sir Same Error ON   
pdal Translate first.pcd -o test.las

 ""PDAL: Couldn't create writer stage of type reader.pcd""

Comment: @Howard Butler, thanks you for the code. The conversion is working well, but output file doesn't preserve original coordinates, changing into some local coordinates. Do you know how to preserve them?

Answer (score 2):

As commented [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250714/converting-las-to-pcd-file-using-pdal#comment398496_251284), if you get error:

> PDAL: Couldn't create writer stage of type writers.pcd

Basically it says, there is no PCL plugin. Hence, you should show library or rebuild PDAL with PCL plugin option to check for build.

First check,

```
pdal --drivers
```

There must exist **writers.pcd Write data in the Point Cloud Library (PCL) format**.

If the plugin does not exist, you should follow this:
https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/1837. And also read the [FAQ](https://pdal.io/faq.html).

Comment: I have created the .pcd but this file when visualized, I see nothing in viewer. pcl-pcl-1.12.1/pcl_viewer (Working on Ubunty 20.04) 

I see this error when viewer is running: 
[fromHandlersToScreen] PointCloud </home/ajit/Downloads/point_clouds/low_quality.pcd-0> requested with an invalid geometry handler (PointCloudGeometryHandlerXYZ)!
[updateColorHandlerIndex] PointCloud with id </home/ajit/Downloads/point_clouds/low_quality.pcd-0> doesn't exist!
.las file i have converted is export from PIX4D