# Converting .pcd LiDAR binary compressed file to .las format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, lidar, las, pcd

I have LiDAR data in the format of .pcd in a binary compressed file (version .7).

How can I convert it into .las format or any other that can be readable by LAStools in ArcGIS 9.3 version ownwards?

I have tried MATLAB 2013b and FUSION, but I don't know how to use these software as I am new to this topic.

Comment: Pdal could be the toolset you are locking for. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250714/converting-las-to-pcd-file-using-pdal

Answer (score 2):

With PDAL it would be the opposite from [Converting .las to .pcd file using PDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250714/converting-las-to-pcd-file-using-pdal):

```
pdal translate input.pcd output.las
```

In this case, you will need to enable the PCL libraries, so the [PDAL PCD Reader](https://pdal.io/stages/readers.pcd.html) can work.

PDAL is a little tricky to get started. Its developers advise beginning using it with [PDAL's Docker](https://pdal.io/quickstart.html).

Comment: The conda binaries have PCL/PCD support too, which should provide an easier alternative than docker for most people.