# Converting .pcd to .las file using PDAL

Tags: las, pdal, pcd

I found [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/294700) on my question.
But when I try to do it, I get this error:

The command:

```
pdal translate D:\Information\bigrotate_frontview.pcd D:\Information\output.las
```

I get this error:

```
Failed to find match for field 'intensity'.
PDAL: writers.las: Unable to convert scaled value (NaN) to int32 for
 dimension 'X' when writing LAS/LAZ file D:\output.las.
```

So I searched for that error and I found [this](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/issues/1846).

So I tried the option `--writers.pcd.xyz=true`

My command looks like this:

```
pdal translate --writers.pcd.xyz=true D:\file.pcd D:\output.las
```

I got the following error:

```
PDAL: Argument references invalid/unused stage: 'writers.pcd'.
```